# Асинхронная инициализация ресурсов

Tags: c#, async-await

Помогите выбрать оптимальный вариант решения следующий проблемы: есть класс `SomeClass`, содержащий некоторые ресурсы - коллекции в виде автоматических св-в.

У класса есть вот таких 2-а метода:

```
private async Task<SomeClass> InitializeResourcesAsync(string connectionString)
{
    SomeFactory = SomeFactory.GetInstance(connectionString);
    SomeResource = await SomeFactory.SomeResource().TryReadAllAsync();
    ...
    return this;
}
```

```
public static Task<SomeClass> CreateInstanceAsync(string connectionString) => new SomeClass().InitializeResourcesAsync(connectionString);
```

И есть несколько классов, которым нужны эти ресурсы для выборки и последующий обработки этих данных.

Вот, допустим, возьмем первый класс `FirstClass`, где эти ресурсы используются. Там есть несколько методов, где происходит выборка и работа с данными из ресурсов.

В чем мой вопрос: поскольку у `SomeClass` метод, инициализирующий объект этого класса, возвращает `Task<T>`, он должен вызываться, соответственно, в методе, помеченным `async`. Где (на каком этапе) мне в `FirstClass` нужно вызвать метод инициализации объекта класса `SomeClass`? Не могу это понять, подскажите.

Comment: Вам обязательно надо инициализировать ресурс отдельным методом? Надо ли хранить ссылку на ресурс? Может лучше хранить ссылку на таск? Вы ожидаете параллельный доступ к ресурсу?

Comment: @tym32167, 1. Не обязательно. 2. Ресурс нужен  в конкретном в классе в определенный момент исключительно для выборки данных. Нужно ли хранить ссылку? Не знаю, честно говоря. 3. Не знаю как лучше. 4. Нет.

Comment: Если он нужен в определенный момент, зачем его загружать заранее? Нельзя загрузить тогда, когда он нужен и закешировать?

Comment: @tym32167, можно инициализировать ресурсы по месту, где это необходимо.  Но тогда все эти методы будут async/await и возвращать Task. И получается, что у меня практически все методы станут async/await. Это нормально? Или я что-то не так понимаю...

Comment: Если вам нужна неблокирующая загрузка, то вам все равно методы делать async/await, ведь в момент, когда ресурс запрошен, нет гарантии, что он уже загружен, загрузка может быть в процессе. Если только вы не дожидаетесь инициализации ресурса где то в другом месте. А вообще да, когда вы переводите синхронный  код в асинхронный, то у вас появятся таски по всему стеку вызовов - так оно обычно и бывает.

Comment: @tym32167, если суммировать, будет более-менее, если инициализировать ресурс по месту использования (уже подразумевая, что вся цепочка синхронных методов превращается в асинхронную)?

Comment: это конечно зависит от вашего конкретного случая, но в большинстве случаев да, имеет смысл грузить данные когда они нужны.

Comment: Хотелось бы видеть больше кода, как вы хотите использовать эти ресурсы. Вполне вероятно, следует применить `Lazy<T>` - это даст возможность присваивать ресурсы без инициализации в одном месте, а использовать в других местах.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov я могу привести примеры, но там обычный linq to objects. А можете привести пример с Lazy? То есть в каком месте это должно быть? Один класс на все ресурсы, где они Lazy или как?

Comment: посмотрите, возможно вам подойдет такая реализация https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Snys7ursIg но имхо лучше сделать приватный конструктор и прикрутить фабричный метод или билдер.